# mySQL - variable in like clause

Tags: mysql, variables, sql-like

how can I use a var in a LIKE clause?

The following code doesn't send a right response...

```
$query = sprintf("
SELECT
place.ID AS id,

IF(
    place.translationID IS NULL,
    place.name,
    placel10n.text
    ) AS cityname,

FROM
places AS place

 LEFT JOIN `l10n-strings` AS placel10n ON (place.translationID = placel10n.translationID AND placel10n.languageCode = 'de')

 WHERE
 place.name LIKE CONCAT('$fchar', '%');
 AND
place.`status` = '1'

");
```

Comment: what is the query when you print that?  is it punctuated properly?

Comment: Why are you using `sprintf` since you are not passing a value to insert into the string?

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this if `$fchar` contains the string that your want to search for:

```
$sql = "
SELECT
place.ID AS id,

IF(
    place.translationID IS NULL,
    place.name,
    placel10n.text
    ) AS cityname,

FROM
places AS place

 LEFT JOIN `l10n-strings` AS placel10n ON (place.translationID = placel10n.translationID AND placel10n.languageCode = 'de')

 WHERE
 place.name LIKE CONCAT('%s', '%');
 AND
place.`status` = '1'";

$query = sprintf($sql,$fchar);
```

So, if `$fchar = 'apple'`, then your query is will try to match 'apple%'.

Answer (score 0):

Think you can just do

```
LIKE '$fchar%';
```

Or with a prepared statement (but not clear about what you want with the usage of sprintf)

```
place.name LIKE :fchar;

$fchar = $fchar'.'%';

$something->bindParam(':fchar', $fchar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: there are some mysql_real_escape_string at the end